# R shiny - Is it possible to make a dynamic UI without user input?

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I was wondering if it was possible to make an UI adapt, but from dataset and not from user input.
I have seen the example of insertUI (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/insertUI.html) but it is not working in my case because it does not belong in a reactive event.

I got this error :

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
>    Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do >something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Here is my server.R code :

```
  i = 2017
  while(TRUE){
    if(file.exists(paste("Challenge_adultes_",i, ".xlsx",sep=""))){

      insertUI(
        selector = "#add",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                       "Insert some text")
      )
      i = i+1
    }else{
      break
    }
  }
```

And my UI :

```
  navbarPage("xxx",
             actionButton("add", "Add UI")
  )
```

So, is it possible to make dynamic UI with insertUI without user input ?
Thank you for your reading.

---

As asked, a full reproductible exemple :

```
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    navbarPage("xxx",
               actionButton("add", "Add UI")

    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

        insertUI(
          selector = "#add",
          where = "afterEnd",
          ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                         "Insert some text")
        )
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: you should provide a full reproducible example.

Comment: I edited and added one, thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of that error message is:

> You tried to do >something that can only be done from inside a
>   reactive expression or observer

You need to put the insertUI() function inside a reactive function. The observe() function is like observeEvent() but instead of a direct trigger, it re-executes whenever its dependencies change. So if you put your changeable data in reactive values, then whenever they change it will re-run the code inside the observe() function.

```
 ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("add", "Add UI") )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                     "Insert some text")
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understood that. So I am unable to make a dynamic UI, NOT depending of a reactive function ? I want to cast this insertUI when the user comes to the page, meaning without any action from him. Is that possible ?

Comment: I see. In that case you probably want to use observe() which doesn't need a direct trigger. This code will run once when the program loads and then again if any dependencies (ex. input$add) change.

Comment: Thx for your answers btw, but "observe(insertUI(selector = "#add",ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),"Insert some text") ))" doesn't seem to work neither.

Comment: You need to wrap the expression inside observe() in a code block with {}. observe({ insertUI() })

Comment: Here is my full try code :
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    navbarPage("xxx",
               actionButton("add", "Add UI")
               
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
        observe({insertUI(
          selector = "#add",
          where = "afterEnd",
          ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                         "Insert some text")
        )})
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

Comment: I think the problem is actually with your UI. You define a navbarPage but don't have any tabPanels so the UI doesn't know how to render properly. If you delete the navbarPage() from your code it will work properly

`ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("add", "Add UI") )`

Comment: Yes it's working now, but the idea is actually to add tabPanel with insertUI ! I want to have one panel for each year, only if they exists in my database. I guess shiny is just not that dynamic. I'll deal with it anyway, thank you for your help !